# SVG to PNG fails to render font

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I have an svg file with custom font families working in the browser.  When I convert the svg to any image type (I have tried png jpg pdf) the font reverts to Arial.  I have the font on the server and it shows on the list of fonts when I use:

```
convert -list font
```

Here is the SVG code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="720" height="288" viewport-fill="white" xml:space="preserve">
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubuntubold';
    src: url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-b-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-b-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-b-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-b-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-b-webfont.svg#ubuntubold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
</style>
</defs>
<g transform="translate(450 149) rotate(0)">
<text font-family="'ubuntubold'" font-size="40" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #0038ff; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-240.54 39)">
<tspan x="0" y="-26" fill="#0038ff">
Bluemoon Entertainment</tspan>
</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

To convert to an image I am using:

```
convert -verbose -density 300 test.svg test_density.png
```

I know there are other image conversion programs out there but my client is very adamant that I use imagemagick.

Comment: @Robert not sure what you mean exactly but if you are asking if I have tried without the single quotes around the font name it gives the same result.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. Did you ever solve it? From what I've read, it seems like you have to install the fonts on the server/machine in order to get it to render properly; otherwise, like you said,it reverts to ariel.

Comment: Unfortunately no... The project was put on hold but will resume again towards the end of this month. I will comment with any updates I have.